# style.css not working in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, header, styles, stylesheet

I have a problem with Wordpress, I've created all needed files including style.css index.php and so on but the page is not styled. In header, among other things, I've put this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: What does your directory look like? How does the parsed HTML look?

Comment: Did you notice that you have two **href** attributes in that link (last line)?

Answer (score 5):

For my case, i had not linked CSS. So i solved it by doing the following:

1. I created a file **header.php** this file had my html code and inside of this file, instead of manually including the css file using link , i called a php function wp_head(); which helps wordpress to take control of my head section.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Wordpress</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

After that i had to create another new file in the themes folder called **functions.php** and linked **style.css** in this file using the following code.

```html
<?php
function files() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
} 
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'files' );

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add stylesheet other than `style.css`, open `function.php` and add the following code.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/bootstrap.css" );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" );
}
```

Add the style.css file using thins:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

Comment: style-name inside wp_enqueue_style,  must be unique. Use add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name1', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/bootstrap.css" );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name2', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" );
}

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your functions.php, it should work.

```
function EnqueueMyStyles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my-custom-style.css', false, '20150320');

    wp_enqueue_style('my-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif+Caption:400,400italic', false, '20150320');

    wp_enqueue_style('my-main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), false, '20150320');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'EnqueueMyStyles');
```

Comment: Your answer is not scoped properly.

Answer (score 3):

Open function.php file and past the following code.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
    function theme_name_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name1', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/style.css" );
       wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name2', get_stylesheet_uri() . "/css/bootstrap.css" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it by looking carefully in my code. This is what I wrote before:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

As well as the following code helped me solved the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

Can you see the difference? Comment below if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

when you also have 2 site URLs or home URLs in your plugins or CSS when you look it up in the inspection on chrome or some browser. And opening this in a new tab (btw this should not be accessible)::

then try to put

"/" without the "" in your localhost or whatever > phpmyadmin > database (of WordPress) > wp_options >> "siteurl" and "home" in option_value

Comment: I mean you can always try this. Easy to go back if it does not work. I did not read your problem. But this was the fix I was looking for and found the solution my self. just remember what was there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `template_url` with `template_directory` in `bloginfo` and all done like:

```
<link ... href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link ... href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In **functions.php** add this code it will link **style.css** file to your WordPress theme

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylecss', get_stylesheet_uri() );  
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```