# Style.css doesn't work on my custom wordpress themes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new at wordpress and I know that there is a lot of answer about my problem but, even I already tries a lot of them and it still doesn't work no matter what I do.

I already make my own custom wordpress themes and it works using bootstrap external link style but my own style.css doesn't apply right. just to make sure I already include it in my header.php too. I make it using this tutorial [converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)

this is my header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>walabi</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>css/style.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.7/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Cache Control -->
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <nav id="paham-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="color: aliceblue"></i></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="career.php">Career</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </nav>
    <!-- Header End -->
```

this is my function.php (first of all how this function.php work? when i'm not even declare it)

```
<?php
//Definir le répertoire du thème
define("THEME_DIR", get_template_directory_uri());

//Enlever le générateur de tags meta pour la sécurité (les gents ne peuvent pas voir quelle version WP)
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');


// ENQUEUE STYLES
function enqueue_styles() {

    /* Main CSS */
    wp_register_style( 'style', THEME_DIR . '/style.css', array(), '1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

this is some answer that i try:

[style-css-in-wordpress-doesnt-work-after-adding-header-php-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424442/style-css-in-wordpress-doesnt-work-after-adding-header-php-file)

[style-css-not-loading-in-wordpress-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680866/style-css-not-loading-in-wordpress-theme)

[style-css-not-working-in-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079255/style-css-not-working-in-wordpress/50562347#50562347)

Just to make sure this is my directory :

[image: this is my themes directory]

in my directory there is:

- career.php
- footer.php
- header.php
- index.php
- function.php
- screenshot.png
- style.css

can someone help me to solve this? I still can't solve this since yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line you have:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>css/style.css">
```

`bloginfo('stylesheet_url')` *is* already the full URL of the stylesheet itself, including the file path and name. So you don't need to append `css/style.css` to it! Just make that

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

And note: The stylesheet should be in the theme directory, not in a separate 'css'  directory for this to work.

Comment: Thankyou, finally it's work like a charm, so it means `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>` this is already the full path of style.css? i don't know about this I means some of the correct answer pointed to add some more path in the end. once again thank you very much ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to make a echo of bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?
Maybe the function dosn't return anything or a wrong path.

For testing, you can also put the path of the css file directly on HTML.

```
 <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>css/style.css">


 <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_CUSTOM_CSS/css/style.css">
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. no i don't want to echo it, it is more like the style.css doesn't take any effect in my code

Comment: I think the path to the css dosn't work, if the echo of the function bloginfo() dosn't return anything it's your function.php And if It's okay you can dev your css directly with the Hardcoded string...

Comment: Shurely you need to inspect your page ;)

Comment: I already inspect this just a moment age as @foreverlogic told me, and it seems my style.css failed to load, you can check it in https://pahamify.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Yes your bloginfo() function dosn't return anything. Actualy it search on pahamify.000webhostapp.com/style.css                                          
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: so what should i do? must i hardcoded it? but i think its not good

Comment: Can I see your path to the css ?

Comment: it is in the same path as header.php, wait I'll update it in the post

Comment: You need to make the absolute path... In your post, is this your www/ folder ?

Comment: @Apayet is correct, it's not putting the full path from your bloginfo() function. Either it's empty, or you need to have it echo out the statement.

Comment: I try to put it in my new header the complete path like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public_html/wp-content/themes/pahamify-scenery-genic/style.css">` but it still not work

Comment: thankyou, it seems @johannes answer is right and it is work, i don't know that the blog_info() is a full path itself, this is his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234152/10158479

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pahamify.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/pahamify-scenery-genic/style.css"> will work

Answer (score 1):

try this on functions.php

```
function enqueue_styles() {

    /* Main CSS */
    wp_register_style( 'style', THEME_DIR . '/style.css', array(), '1', 'all');
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_register_style( 'material', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.7/css/mdb.min.css');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );

}
```

Comment: first of all thankyou for your answer but when I try this code but nothing happen, it still the same

Answer (score 1):

Have you inspected the source code and seen if the stylesheet is being called on the page? If so, try clicking or pasting the link into another tab and making sure it loads, and if not, try to compare the path it's trying to load the CSS from, to what the actual path is.

You can also right click on the page and click inspect, and go to the network tab and reload that page, it should tell you if that stylesheet is being loaded or failed to load.

Let me know when you do this and I'll check back and see if you need any more help.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, I try this and when i reload it, style.css doesn't load or failed and it is not in the listed in network, you can check it in this link https://pahamify.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: when i see it again, style.css is there but status is failed

Comment: So your path to the stylesheet is what the issue is. Where did you upload it via FTP or however you put it on the server?

Comment: It seems like the stylesheet is trying to be pulled from the root path of the site. Try replacing "<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>css/style.css">" with "<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/my/css/style.css">"

Comment: do not put /public_html/ in there. That is incorrect and can cause security issue if you're not careful. Remove that and try again.

Comment: i see, so i musn't put in in public_html since it will turn to security problem, thank you for the advise ^.^ and it already solved now thank you for help me this whole time